# Alternative Definition of convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, definition

In my course, I've learned that f is convex if for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$:  $f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)\leq (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)$.

Now I saw a lot of people using the definition
for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda \notin (0,1)$: $(1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y) \leq f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)$.

Is there an easy way to proof that these definitions are equivalent?

Edit: f is definied on a convex set and in the second definition $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y$ is in this set.

Comment: The first inequality says that secant lines to the graph lie above the graph itself between the two intersection points; the second inequality says that those secant lines lie below the graph to one side or the other of the intersection points. My instinct is to prove that both of these properties are equivalent to the graph lying above any of its tangent lines (at least when $f$ is differentiable).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence is based purely on algebraic manipulations. I will just illustrate it with one special case. Suppose $\lambda >1$ and the second inequality holds. Replace $x$ by $\frac x {\lambda}$ and $y$ by $\frac y {\lambda}$.  Divide the second inequality by $\lambda$. Some simple algebraic manipulation reduces the inequality to

$$ f(\frac y {\lambda}) \leq (1-\frac  1 {\lambda})f(\frac x {\lambda})+\frac 1 {\lambda} f((1-\lambda)\frac x {\lambda}+y)$$ which is  special case of the first inequality. [Note that  $$ \frac y {\lambda} = (1-\frac  1 {\lambda})(\frac x {\lambda})+\frac 1 {\lambda} ((1-\lambda)\frac x {\lambda}+y)$$